# PHP DateTime object

Tags: php

Why in the first example i got minutes and seconds 00:00 and in the second example, when no hour is specified, i got actual time?
I wanna always values 0 if in the date from which the object was created that value isn`t defined.

```
echo DateTime::createFromFormat('j.n.Y H', "3.4.2012 22")->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
```

**Output:** 2012-04-03 22:00:00

```
echo DateTime::createFromFormat('j.n.Y', "3.4.2012")->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
```

**Output:** 2012-04-03 23:05:45

**Excpected output:** 2012-04-03 00:00:00

Comment: When you specify part of a time it will assume zeros for the missing parts. If you provide no time it assumes the current time.

Comment: @JohnConde: hm bad behavior, ty for answer

Comment: If you wanted "2012-04-03 00:00:00" as the result, use: `format('Y-m-d 00:00:00')` instead.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This will give your wished format:

```
echo DateTime::createFromFormat('!j.n.Y', "3.4.2012")->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');


Output: 2012-04-03 00:00:00
Excpected output: 2012-04-03 00:00:00
```

Ref: http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.createfromformat.php

> ! Resets all fields (year, month, day, hour, minute, second, fraction
> and timzone information) to the Unix Epoch    Without !, all fields will
> be set to the current date and time.

In other words, without the exclamation mark `!`, if you don't specify any of H (hours), i (minutes), and s (seconds), the current OS system time running the PHP script is used.

If any of the elements `H`, `i`, or `s` are given, the system time is not used. In effect, 0 will fill all unspecified time elements. For example:

```
echo DateTime::createFromFormat('j.n.Y H', "3.4.2012 22")->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
//=> 2012-04-03 22:00:00

echo DateTime::createFromFormat('j.n.Y i', "3.4.2012 22")->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
//=> 2012-04-03 00:22:00

echo DateTime::createFromFormat('j.n.Y s', "3.4.2012 22")->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
//=> 2012-04-03 00:00:22
```